# Вышибло из стека

Tags: дефект

Перешел на страницу [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997968/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-js/998050) и я не увидел кнопки **"Править"**!, Подправив ответ [kidar2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13076/kidar2) обнаружил, что я разлогинен. Что могло пойти не так?